# Is it possible to change the get_posts() or wp_query() function to alter the results that are returned?

Tags: php

I have a somewhat difficult question.

Is it possible to change the get_posts() or wp_query() function to alter the results that are returned?

- For example, you want to show some posts/pages with a specific meta lower in the list than other pages
- You want to show the post with post type 'custom' lower in the list than other pages

Is there some hook for this :)?

Answer (score 0):

do you mean something like this?

https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/pre_get_posts/

Here you can alter the query before it is actually run.